# Mobile search results don't tell you when nothing was found

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, mobile-web

[Searching for `[live-refresh] tags sidebar`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blive-refresh%5D+tags+sidebar) returns no results, and the full site page responds accordingly:

> Your search returned no matches.

However, the mobile search just dumps you on an empty page:

[image: search results page with zero results]

While you can infer there weren't any results from the emptiness, the mobile results page should behave consistently with the full site version and just state this explicitly.

Comment: Wait, how do you search on mobile?

Comment: There's a search box shown when you expand the header section using the arrow on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed after the next build, thanks for the catch!